# Autolayout grid button constant spacing

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, xcode9

Autolayout is a total mystery.

So, I have this view I made in the interface builder. 
[image: the view in the interface builder]

It's made of custom buttons that are aligned.

If I try this view, here what's happening. 
[image: iPhone 8 plus, everything is fine]
On the iPhone 8 plus, everything is fine. 
[image: But on smaller screens, it's messy]
But on smaller screens, it's messy

As you can imagine, I want this grid to stay aligned, but to organise itself so it fits in any screen size. 
I tried autolayout for hours, al I can get is a messy hell.

Two questions : 
1 - Is there a way to set up the autolayout to get this done right ? And if yes, please, how ? 
2 - Is it possible to create a view for iPhone 8, a view for iPhone 4, etc. ?

Thanks !

Comment: which controller you use?

Comment: You have two options...you could look into using either a `UICollectionView`, making your cell to look like your views here, and setting the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` to be equal to `view.frame.size.width/2`, or create a `UIStackView` to hold each 'row'

Comment: What do you want to happen when you rotate the device, or when you use an iPad? Do you want more columns? or do you want to keep 2 columns, but center the buttons? make them bigger? do you want to keep the bottom row (3 buttons) visible all the time, or have it scroll out of view?

Comment: @matt I'm not the only one saying it's a mysterie, Apple does it too : https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Put your both columns of buttons inside StackView (middle button)

[image]

2) Put these two views inside another stack view for horizontal alignment

3) Center this second stackView for x axis

4) Attach it to top with offset about 16 points

5) Put bottom buttons inside third stackView

6) Attach third stackView to second one with left / top offsets

The job for you is only to understand this and do - it should work :)

Answer (score 2):

it's more easy to use collection view for this grid layout and use only one stack view for bottom most items.and bind collection view and stackview to each other.